# creating VENN diagramm in power BI with more than 4 categories

Tags: powerbi

you being so helpful all the time.
i am facing new more challenges in work.
I need to create venn diagram in power BI as client data it has to be 8 categories so 8 circles need to be  joined.
by MAQ software
[image]
it has limit upto 4 categories.

when i use ultimate VENN diagram it getting stuck a lot of times in between
[image]

so can you please help

categories as mentioned below and in each catgeory there is servname name and count like
in AD -
server1 count1
server2 count1

in AD and SCCM
server 2 count1
server 3 count1

[image]

Comment: Give some sample data.

Comment: there are 8 categories i have mentioned in request, each category has some server so common servers create venn diagram